# Redirect Page Path to Homepage using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

How can I redirect all of the sub pages that include a particular path (/home-2016/) back to my home page?  I am using the below code in my .htaccess file, but it is not working. I can't seem to find a solution.

I want to redirect the following

1. `https://www.example.com/home-2016/` to `https://www.example.com`
2. `https://www.example.com/home-2016/...` to `https://www.example.com`

```
RewriteRule ^home-2016/(.*) / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: "but it is not working" - What is happening exactly? The code you posted should already do as you require (but it can be simplified). However, it depends on your other directives and where you've put this rule - you can't just put it anywhere (as with any script). We'll need to see your complete `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Thanks, @MrWhite! I moved it up in the file and it works!

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^home-2016/(.*) / [R=301,NC,L]
> ```

This rule already does as you require, but it would seem you were putting the rule in the wrong place. Redirects like this would need to go near the top of the `.htaccess` file, *before* any existing rewrites (like a CMS front-controller pattern).

However, this rule can also be simplified, since you don't need the capturing subpattern.

The following will do the same, but with a more efficient regex:

```
RewriteRule ^home-2016/ / [R=301,NC,L]
```

Unless you specifically need a case-insensitive match, you should remove the `NC` flag.